# Positioning images and that are unhidden

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on a project to have hidden images appear when the button is pressed. My only problem is that when I click on the button the image appears. I then have to click on the button again for it to show up in the correct area of my view controller. Can someone help point me in the right direction please?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.image.hidden = true
        image.frame = CGRectMake(50, 75, 30, 35)
    }

    @IBAction func test(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.image.hidden = false
        image.image = UIImage(named: "diamond.png")
        image.frame = CGRectMake(50, 75, 30, 35)
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you using self and not in referring to the image? And you might want to load the image in viewDidLoad or before you set hidden to false.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not help, but i would recommend that instead of using the image.hidden property, set the alpha value of the image. So `image.alpha = 0` for hidden and `image.alpha = 1` for visible. This would also allow you to then fade the image in and out if you wanted. Additionally I would set the image in viewDidLoad() instead of the Action. Here's how I would redo your code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.image.alpha = 0
        image.image = UIImage(named: "diamond.png")
        image.frame = CGRectMake(50, 75, 30, 35)
    }

    @IBAction func test(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.image.alpha = 1
    }
}
```

I also believe setting the frame twice isn't useful as the frame will be set in viewDidLoad()

Comment: Dufud6 Thank you for your comment. I'm still new to coding so trying to get the syntax down packed. I see your point. Going to try this out. I never used alpha before. Thank you!